# chrome.idle.onStateChanged not triggering function

Tags: javascript, permissions, google-chrome-app

I am building a note taking app for Chrome and I want the app to save its progress when the user stops typing, but I can't get chrome.idle to trigger a state change

```
chrome.idle.setDetectionInterval(10);

chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(
    function (newState) {
        var messageElement = document.querySelector("#message");
        messageElement.innerHTML = "idle";
        if (newState === "idle")
            save();
    }
);
```

Chrome requires a permission to access the idle functionality so I have included the idle permission in the manifest. However, when I load the app  with the extensions tool and view the permissions, it says I have no special permissions. Could this have anything to do with why the idle state change isn't triggering my function?

Comment: "Stops typing"? This API will only detect state like "haven't touched the computer at all".

Comment: This is from Google's documentation "The system is considered idle if intervalInSeconds (10) seconds have elapsed since the last user input detected." Wouldn't this mean in the example that when the user hasn't typed anything for 10 seconds, the app would be considered idle? Or am I misunderstanding what is happening?

Comment: This is what I have been reading to learn about the idle API [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/idle)

Comment: No user input to the system, not just your app.

Comment: You are right about the whole system needing to be idle and not just my app. How do apps like Evernote go about saving the text?

Comment: Probably by listening to DOM events; if there were none, an interval timer triggers, otherwise the timer is reset on each input. If I were to guess, that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, the issue is that the minimum value setDetectionInterval will accept is 15. I found some code that is trying to do exactly what I am doing in a Safari Online book...

```
chrome.idle.setDetectionInterval(15);

chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(
    function (state) {
        if (state === "idle" && dirty)
            save();
    }
);
```

This code is almost exactly the same, but this version works and mine didn't. The console prints an error that says the minimum value for the interval is 15 seconds where I was trying to check every 10. So I switched my code to check every 15 seconds and everything worked

Comment: Did you use it in WebPage or its only working as APP? can i use it if i run the page as http://localhost/index.html ?

Comment: I was using this in a Chrome Web Store app, so I was packaging the code and loading it using the Chrome package manager. Chrome OS then handled the launching of the page. The chrome-extension should work in a similar way. Actually doing a webpage would maybe work in Chrome, but I haven't tried it. When I was doing this there wasn't a lot of info for building a Chrome Web Store app, but there was a lot of overlap in the Chrome extension documentation that worked for web store apps.

Comment: Also, the book I was going through at the time was an O'Reilly book "Programming Chrome Apps" http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033776.do